# Configuring JAAS on Liferay Portal

Tags: liferay, jaas

Could anybody provide pointers to configure jaas on liferay portal using customized login module.

Answer (score 0):

check below link 
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/89530
may be it's helpful.